# Get directory name from path in Smarty only

Tags: php, directory, smarty

**I cannot assign my own PHP function.** (I just have access to the TPL file).

So far I got `{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}`, which returns something like `/foo/bar.xin`. With built in functions, I'd like to get `/foo/`.

Comment: Can you use the `{php}` tags (which are deprecated going forward)?

Comment: Yep I can, as far as I know. I'll replace them once I get PHP access.

Comment: If you can, then you can do your own manipulation using PHP. I hesitate to offer an answer, since 1) I don't know the context in which you want to use the value, 2) I don't have access to a Smarty parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted, `{php}` tags are deprecated, but you can do the following:

```
{php}
$php_self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$path = substr($php_self, 0, strrpos($php_self, '/'));
// assign a variable to Smarty
$this->assign('path',$path);
{/php}
Path: <strong>{$path}</strong>
```

I haven't been able to test this, since I don't have a parser at my disposal, but it follows the example on the Smarty documentation page:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `$path` appears as empty/null, i.e. doesn't appear, and I'm not sure how to debug it. `echo/print` in the `{php}` tag doesn't display either, nor does `{$path}` outside of it.

Comment: @Lazlo - Are you sure you're allowed to use `{php}` tags? This can be turned on/off by whoever controls the Smarty object you're using.

Comment: Then maybe I am not, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Lazlo - I'm not sure if you're trying to display the value or what, but you can use [string modifiers](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl) to potentially trim the filename off PHP_SELF.

Comment: @Jared: I assume `|truncate:length` could do it, but how to get the length?

Comment: @Lazlo - That's a good question. I guess trial and error? What are you doing with the path?

Comment: @Jared: I use it as a prefix for an absolute link: `{$smarty.server.SERVER_NAME}{$prefix}{$relativeURL}`. I only have access to `{$relativeURL}` (as far as I know).

Comment: @Lazlo - Do you need it on the server or on the client?

Comment: On the server, it's for an AddThis parameter.

Comment: @Lazlo - So in other words, you need to be able to assign a variable for use on your server. This is probably a stupid question, but will your Smarty admin allow you to add some PHP to handle this scenario? If not, I'm not sure without trying some different approaches.

Comment: @Jared: He will, eventually. I just wanted to get this task done today, but it can wait. Thanks for your help though, I'll mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: @Lazlo - Ok, thanks for that. I imagine if they have it really locked down, you probably couldn't do it without code-side help (since you're trying to do application logic in the display logic). Smarty is controversial simply for giving designers too much access to the underlying PHP function/object space (as compared to Flexy et al).

Answer (score 1):

`{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF | dirname}` will return `/foo` assuming the dirname function is enabled (see `php_modifiers` in [Smarty security settings](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl)).

Answer (score 0):

```
{$smarty.server.DOCUMENT_ROOT}
```

will return server path